# Bootstrap 4.3.1 Upgrade: No mixin named font-size

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

I have an Angular project that was running Bootstrap 4beta. I upgraded via command line `npm install bootstrap --save` to the latest Bootstrap 4.3.1. I also did `npm install`. But when I do `ng serve` I get the following error: No mixin named font-size. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The following is my _mixins.scss file

```
// Toggles
//
// Used in conjunction with global variables to enable certain theme features.

// Vendor
@import "vendor/rfs";

// Deprecate
@import "mixins/deprecate";

// Utilities
@import "mixins/breakpoints";
@import "mixins/hover";
@import "mixins/image";
@import "mixins/badge";
@import "mixins/resize";
@import "mixins/screen-reader";
@import "mixins/size";
@import "mixins/reset-text";
@import "mixins/text-emphasis";
@import "mixins/text-hide";
@import "mixins/text-truncate";
@import "mixins/visibility";

// // Components
@import "mixins/alert";
@import "mixins/buttons";
@import "mixins/caret";
@import "mixins/pagination";
@import "mixins/lists";
@import "mixins/list-group";
@import "mixins/nav-divider";
@import "mixins/forms";
@import "mixins/table-row";

// // Skins
@import "mixins/background-variant";
@import "mixins/border-radius";
@import "mixins/box-shadow";
@import "mixins/gradients";
@import "mixins/transition";

// // Layout
@import "mixins/clearfix";
@import "mixins/grid-framework";
@import "mixins/grid";
@import "mixins/float";
```

[image]

Comment: Your `styles.scss` is using a mixin which is no longer available in your current version of Bootstrap. Without showing the relevant code from `styles.scss`, your question is unanswerable. A possible fix [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28233).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu please see updated styles.scss file

Comment: you should show your `/app/src/styles.scss` file, not _mixins.scss. Also check your `styles.scss` file for any missing semi colons.